# Change the animation dismissViewController to be equal to the popViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, popviewcontroller

In my application I have popViewController and dismissViewController.
In some dismissViewController I liked to do animation of popViewController to achieve a consistency between transactions . is it possible?

Comment: Hi Pedro, the question is a little hard to understand. Could you please edit it so it's clearer what you mean.

Comment: I wanted the animation output views stay the same, regardless of the form I use to remove the view of the scree